# code for discerning palindromes

Tags: python

```
def is_palindrome(s):

    if s == ' ':
        return True

    if s[0] != s[-1]:
        return False

    return is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

This is my code and it doesn't work.
It works for cases such as abab, but not abba.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: abab is not a palindrome

Comment: `def is_palindrome(s): return s == s[::-1]`

Comment: It's also going to get an infinite recursion if len(s) is odd.

Comment: Unless the string is huge...

Comment: @hayden: Actually, it won't. When `len(s)` is odd, it'll test for the empty string, then throw an IndexError.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - where is the IndexError? `s[0]`,`s[-1]`, and `s[1:-1]` are all valid for a single-character string.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: It's the *empty* string that will give an IndexError. Next iteration, the one-character string is reduced to an empty string, the test for a `' '` space fails, so then it'll test `s[0] != s[-1]`.

Comment: Simple palindrome test:
`if x == x[:-1]: return True # x[::-1] is x backwards`

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_palindrome(s): 
  return s == s[::-1]
```

if you are concerned about *huge* strings, you can use iterators:

```
def is_palindrome(xs):
  return all( imap( lambda a,b: a == b, iter(xs), reversed(xs)) )
```

Comment: Obviously this will choke up if the string is massive

Comment: In that case, you can do it with reversed iterators

Comment: The recursive version will blow up as well...

Comment: Who says about recursive version?

Comment: That was meant in response to @JakobBowyer and his concerns about big inputs ;)

Comment: @JakubM.: You could replace `imap( lambda a,b: a == b, iter(xs), reversed(xs))` with `a == b for a, b in izip(xs, reversed(xs))` (just to follow Guido's preference of explicit iteration instead of using mapping and lambdas, AFAIR). The other thing is [Paul McGuire's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090488/code-for-discerning-palindromes#comment19488088_14090568) about unnecessary comparison after you have compared first half of the elements (you begin comparison with `xs[0] == xs[-1]` and end with `xs[-1] == xs[0]`). See my answer for my approach to this subject (using iterators).

Answer (score 3):

If you *have* to use recursion, use a better termination clause:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    if s[0] != s[-1]:
        return False
    return is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

So, when your string is reduced to 1 or 0 characters, you have a palindrome.

This gives:

```
>>> is_palindrome('abba')
True
>>> is_palindrome('palindrome')
False
>>> is_palindrome('aba')
True
```

Your original error was to test for a space, while `s` is being reduced to an *empty* string instead. Testing for `s == ''` would also work, but since a single-character string also qualifies as a palindrome you may as well make that an explicit termination test.

Comment: Worth mentioning that recursion isn't the Python's strongest point, AFAIK

Comment: @JakubM.: This is probably homework to teach recursion..

Comment: While this is good advice, I like AshRj's solution better, as it identifies and fixes the specific bug in the OP's posted code.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Which is taken from the comment (now deleted) on the question I made earlier. Just sayin'. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if s == '':  # <-- See this change, '' instead of ' '
        return True
    if s[0] != s[-1]:
        return False
    return is_palindrome(s[1:-1])


>>> is_palindrome('')
True
>>> is_palindrome('a')
True
>>> is_palindrome('aba')
True
>>> is_palindrome('abba')
True
>>> is_palindrome('abcba')
True
>>> is_palindrome('abcbac')
False
>>> is_palindrome(' ')
True
>>> is_palindrome('able was i ere i saw elba')
True
```

This is not a good implementation at all, though. You should try a different approach.

Comment: Ah, of course, in that case you look at an empty string too (`'c'[1:-1] == ''`).

Comment: I am sorry if I did! I cannot tell people what to vote on. Not sure why you got a downvote though.

Comment: Whats the downvote for, now ?

Comment: I don't get the downvote either - this fixes the bug in the OP's posted code, testing against ' ' instead of ''.

Comment: Might also want to add `.lower()` as part of the test, as traditional palindromes are not typically case-sensitive (left as an exercise for the OP). You could also probably get some extra credit if you show a solution that ignores punctuation, such as a terminating '.'.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should handle large inputs efficiently (along with testing the values until the middle):

```py
from itertools import islice, izip

def is_palindrome(s):
    middle = len(s) // 2
    return all(i[0] == i[1] for i in islice(izip(s, reversed(s)), middle + 1))
```

In Python 3 you could just replace `izip()` with `zip()`.

Comment: By "efficient" I assume you mean in terms of memory, but this solution does double work, likely costing our OP some points on his homework. Zipping `s` and `reversed(s)` will compare `i[0]==i[last]` in the first tuple, and `i[last]==i[0]` in the last one.  Can you come up with a version of this that stops in the middle?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: please see it now, I think it should now work as you expected